# Index an ordered vector with random number of repeating values

Tags: r

```
df<-data.frame(old=c(1,1,1,5,7,7,7,11,13,13,16,18,20,20,20,20,25,25,25,29),
               new=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10))

   old new
1    1   1
2    1   1
3    1   1
4    5   2
5    7   3
6    7   3
7    7   3
8   11   4
9   13   5
10  13   5
11  16   6
12  18   7
13  20   8
14  20   8
15  20   8
16  20   8
17  25   9
18  25   9
19  25   9
20  29  10
```

How do I turn `old` into `new` easily? Basically it's the order of values repeated the same number of times. The values are always increasing.

Thanks in advance. I don't even know how to Google something this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::consecutive_id` or `data.table::rleid` to get an identifier for each run of identical values:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  old = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 13, 13, 16, 18, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 29)
)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table)

df |>
  mutate(new = consecutive_id(old))
#>    old new
#> 1    1   1
#> 2    1   1
#> 3    1   1
#> 4    5   2
#> 5    7   3
#> 6    7   3
#> 7    7   3
#> 8   11   4
#> 9   13   5
#> 10  13   5
#> 11  16   6
#> 12  18   7
#> 13  20   8
#> 14  20   8
#> 15  20   8
#> 16  20   8
#> 17  25   9
#> 18  25   9
#> 19  25   9
#> 20  29  10

df |>
  mutate(new = rleid(old))
#>    old new
#> 1    1   1
#> 2    1   1
#> 3    1   1
#> 4    5   2
#> 5    7   3
#> 6    7   3
#> 7    7   3
#> 8   11   4
#> 9   13   5
#> 10  13   5
#> 11  16   6
#> 12  18   7
#> 13  20   8
#> 14  20   8
#> 15  20   8
#> 16  20   8
#> 17  25   9
#> 18  25   9
#> 19  25   9
#> 20  29  10
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have known it was in `dplyr` but had no idea how to phrase a search for it.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially just checking when the old column changes. You can do this in a variety of ways, but the easiest is checking if the previous value in df$old matches the current one, then find the cumulative sum of that:

```
df$new <- cumsum(df$old != dplyr::lag(df$old, default = 0))
```

or

```
df$new <- cumsum(df$old != c(0, df$old[-nrow(df)]))
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
df |> mutate(new = cumsum(old != lag(df$old, default = 0)))
```

or

```
df$new <- cumsum(diff(c(0, df$old)) > 0)
```

or

```
df |> mutate(new = cumsum(diff(c(0, old)) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, these all work. I had a clunky `ifelse` method along the same lines but i figured there must be a specific function that does this, and of course there is in `dplyr` and also `data.table`. See the answer from @stefan